# Basic python socket server application doesnt result in expected output

Tags: python, sockets

Im trying to write a basic server / client application in python, where the clients sends the numbers 1-15 to the server, and the server prints it on the server side console.

Code for client:

```
import socket
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8303))
def updateX():
    x = 0
    while (x < 15):
        x
        clientsocket.send(format(x))
        print x
        x = x+1

updateX()
```

server:

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 8303
s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections
connection, address = s.accept()

while True:
    connection, address = s.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(64)
    print buf
```

The output of running the client while the server is live results in either no output, prints only 1, or prints only 12. Ideas?

Comment: Where is your format()?  Make sure you delimit your numbers from each other...

Answer (score 2):

Before entering the main loop on the server side, you accept a connection:

```
connection, address = s.accept()
```

But then in the loop itself you begin by accepting a connection:

```
while True:
    connection, address = s.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(64)
    print buf
```

As a result, you never read from the first connection.  That's why you don't see any output.

Note also that it's wrong (for what you're trying to do) to accept a new connection on every iteration.  Even if you keep making new client connections, the server will accept a connection on each iteration and read from the socket once, but then continue the next iteration and wait for a new connection, never reading more data sent by a client.  You should be making multiple `recv` calls on the same connection object instead.

You might find [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors:

- socket.send() might send only partial content, use socket.sendall() instead
- `format(12)` returns `'12'` therefore even if your code sends all numbers and the server correctly receives them then it sees `'01234567891011121314'` i.e., individual numbers are not separated
- double socket.accept() [mentioned by @Alp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23306038/4279) leads to ignoring the very first connection
- socket.recv(64) may return less than 64 bytes, you need a loop until it returns an empty bytestring (meaning EOF) or use socket.makefile()

Client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Send numbers in the range 0..14 inclusive as bytes e.g., 10 -> b'\n'

Usage: python client.py [port]
"""
import sys
import socket
from contextlib import closing

port = 8686 if len(sys.argv) < 2 else int(sys.argv[1])
with closing(socket.create_connection(('localhost', port))) as sock:
    sock.sendall(bytearray(range(15))) # send each number as a byte
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)    # no more sends/receives
```

You need to know how numbers are separated in the data. In this case, a fixed format is used: each number is a separate byte. It is limited to numbers that are less than 256.

And the corresponding server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Usage: python server.py [port]
"""
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import socket
from contextlib import closing

host = 'localhost'
port = 8686 if len(sys.argv) < 2 else int(sys.argv[1])

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # ipv4 version
try:
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)
    print("listening TCP on {host} port {port}".format(**vars()))
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with closing(conn), closing(conn.makefile('rb')) as file:
            for byte in iter(lambda: file.read(1), b''):
                # print numerical value of the byte as a decimal number
                print(ord(byte), end=' ')
            print("") # received all input from the client, print a newline
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Keyboard interrupt received, exiting.')
finally:
    s.close()
```