# Corrupt file for stdout in python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

i wanted to program a python script which runs several c++ programs from a list of jobs.

I think it works fine, but i have a problem with the output file, which seems to be damaged or something. Anyways i can't open them. Maybe you guys can help me.

```
import multiprocessing
import psutil
import subprocess
import time

jobs2Do = True

while (jobs2Do):    #Ever-running program

cpuLoad = cpuLoad + psutil.cpu_percent()

if (cpuLoad < 90):
    with open('JobQueue.txt', 'r') as f:
        first_line = f.readline()
        path = f.readline()
        f.close()
    if (first_line != ""):
        print "Opening " + first_line
        process = subprocess.Popen( first_line, shell=True, stdout=open(path,"w"),stderr=open("error.log","w"))

        with open('JobQueue.txt', 'r') as fin:
            data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
        with open('JobQueue.txt', 'w') as fout:
            fout.writelines(data[2:])
        with open("JobsDone.txt", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(first_line)
            myfile.write(path)
        myfile.close()

    else:
        print "No more jobs... waiting for new jobs...."
        time.sleep(10)
```

Okay, so what i (want to) do is: I check, if the cpu has some free capacities, if so, open the file with the jobs and get the command, which is in the first line of that file, and the path to where all the output of the program should be saved to. This is always in the second line of the file.

Then I want to open that subprocess, and put the stdout to my preffered path and put the errorstream to wherever. Finally, I delete the job from the list and start from the beginning.

My Problem now is, that the stdout=open(path,"w") seems to be sort of corrupt, because I can't access or even delete it, but I can see it in the folder.

Maybe you guys have an idea, what I did wrong.

Thanks for your effort!

NonStopAggroPop

PS: Maybe I should also add, that the c++-programs are running for a longer period of time. So what I intentionally wanted to do is just let the program execute nohup ./c++ [arguments] and stream the output to a specific file, like it would if I typed it in the console.

PPS: And I want to be able to start multiple c++-programs while the others are still runing, until my cpu reaches 100% usage.

Comment: Surely, you can remove the c++ tag?

Comment: Yep, you're right, the tag was suggested, but mainly its a python problem. sorry!

Comment: Maybe the sub-process is still working ? try placing `process.communicate()` just after the `process = subprocess.Popen(...` line.it'll wait for sub-process to terminate.

Comment: you don't have to close files, if you open them with *with*. You don't wait for the process, which could bring some problems with freeing resources, like closing files.

Comment: where do you fill the JobQueue? There is a race condition between reading the whole file and writing back without the first two lines.

Comment: if and while are no functions, so there is no need in putting parens around the conditions.

Comment: I write the JobQueue before i start the python script, and maybe i can edit it while it is running.

@Daniel Yes, I just want them to start and stream their output to "path". When they are done, i don't care. but you think the closing of the stdout isn't done correctly? how could i achieve this?

Comment: coming from c++, so excuse my minor knowledge of python ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Problem now is, that the `stdout=open(path,"w")` seems to be sort of corrupt, because I can't access or even delete it, but I can see it in the folder.

The issue is that `path = f.readline()` return a string with a *newline* at the end. `open(path, 'w')` on some systems doesn't care and creates the file with a newline at the end. Try `print(os.listdir('.'))` to see `\n` in the filename.

To fix it, just remove the newline: `path = path.strip()`.

---

There are other unrelated issues in your code:

- you are mixing tabs and spaces for indentation. Never do that: it makes the visual indentation different from the one Python sees as it currently is in your question. Either always use tabs or spaces, not both. You can configure your editor to insert 4 spaces when you hit Tab key.
- you probably meant `cpuLoad = psutil.cpu_percent()` instead of `cpuLoad = cpuLoad + psutil.cpu_percent()` that increases each iteration of the loop for no reason
- remove the newline from the command and remove `shell=True`. Don't use shell unless it is necessary (it is a good habit that sometimes may be broken if you know what you are doing):

  ```
  import shlex

  process = Popen(shlex.split(command),
                  stdout=output_file, stderr=stderr_file)
  ```
- use `with`-statements for the code to be compatible with other Python implementations such as Jython, Pypy:

  ```
  with open(path, 'w') as output_file:
       with open('error.log', 'w') as stderr_file:
           process = Popen(shlex.split(command),
                           stdout=output_file, stderr=stderr_file)
  ```

  otherwise the files may remain open in the parent process.
- remove `f.close()`, `myfile.close()` after the `with`-statement that closes the
  file by itself even if an exception occurs that is its purpose, its
  raison d'être. `.close()` is harmless but pointless in this
  case
- use `if not first_line.strip():` to test whether the first line is blank (contains only whitespace)
- the whole idea of manually editing `JobQueue.txt` is fragile. Nothing stops Python process to read only partial input. You could use a dedicated command to add new jobs e.g.,  `at`-like utility. And implement it however you like e.g., listen on a port for a new jobs in the main script and send jobs in `at`-like utility. Here's a code example of a [the very basic socket client and server in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23307026/4279). Or use other IPC methods.

Comment: Thats it! Really appreciate it!

For your second bullet point: I take a mean value of the cpuLoad, so i accumulate the value for 5 times, wait a little bit in between and then divide it by 5. i erased it from the sample code in order to make it more readable. 

One point though: if I remove "shell=True" its not working. I get the error: in subprocess.py in execute_child raise child exception "no such file or directory". but with shell=True it runs like i wanted it.

Really (!!!) appreciate your help! Have a very nice sunday sir!

Comment: @NonStopAggroPop: if you want a mean value; look at the description of `interval` parameter for `psutil.cpu_percent`. Unless you want to run a builtin shell command such as `help` in bash or you want to create a pipeline e.g., `a | b` then you don't need `shell=True`. Running with the shell may have undesirable side-effect e.g., it may change how `process.kill()` works. Try to specify the full path to the command. Look at `print(shlex.split(command))` and make sure it has expected value